# For the survival analysis package in R, what is the log-likelihood of "survreg( Surv(time, censor) ~ age, dist="exponential")"?

Tags: survival, exponential-distribution

I am currently trying to read through examples from http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/examples/asa/asa_ch1_r.htm. One of the models I saw was:

```
survreg( Surv(time, censor) ~ age, dist="exponential").
```

I know that for the case where there ISN'T a covariate (`age` in this case), we have:

`survreg( Surv(time, censor) ~ 1, dist="exponential")`, and the log-likelihood here is:

$l(\theta) = \log(\theta)-\theta t$.

Would anyone know how this log likelihood would change with a covariate? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be more accurate to say that:

$l(\theta) = \sum( \log(\theta) )- \sum( \theta Y_i)$

$l(\theta) = n_u \log(\theta) )- \sum( \theta Y_i)$  where u's are uncensored and Y's are observation times

When there is no covariate;

$\delta \log L/ \delta \lambda = n_u/\lambda - w$ where $w = \sum Y_i$ (i.e total person-years, censored or not)

So the MLE for $\lambda$ is just what you would expect: events per total person years of observation. For models with covariate, you substitute $\lambda(t|X_i)$ with $\lambda(t)*exp(beta_1*X)$ and then redo the summations. On the log hazard scale it turns into a linear regression.